# Batch insert from PHP using MySql stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a Java developer, but i would like to write some test application with PHP. So far, i used on using JDBC driver and batch insert to insert large datasets from Java to my MySql database. Also, on DB side i always prefer to have stored procedures called by JDBC because that way i was able to manipulate my Java application a bit without recompiling.
With PHP, on the other hand, i don't have much experience. I know that with PHP i can make batched db inserts by coining command in following manner (pseudo code):

```
$command = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ";
for-each
$command.="(xx,yy,zz),"
```

But with that approach i nave to write "raw" database queries. Something i don't like (for example because someone good with MySql but having no clue about programming won't be able to help me much).

What would be the correct way with PHP to call MySql stored procedures to insert data in batched manner? JDBC has something like "addBatch()" and "insertBatch()". Php?

Comment: You're mixing concepts. You can call a stored procedure to do any set of MySQL actions you would like but MySQL doesn't even have the concept of "batch". PHP is more organic than Java and would require you write something to insert a large number of records.

Comment: If you need help still please clarify what you mean by batch. There are fast ways and slow ways. But at the moment you need to define where that data exists for your question is vague.